# LeetCode Problem3: Longest Substring Without Repeating Characters

Tags: c++, substring, string-length

This problem is try to:

> Given a string, find the length of the longest substring without
>   repeating characters.

And the example:

> Given "nfpdmpi", the answer is "nfpdm", which the length is 5.

And my code is:

```
int lengthOfLongestSubstring(string s) {
    unordered_set<char> sub;
    size_t max_len = 0;

    for (int i=0 ; i<s.size() ; ++i) {
        if ( sub.find(s[i]) != sub.end() ) {
            max_len = ( sub.size() > max_len ? sub.size() : max_len );
            sub.erase( sub.find(s[i]), sub.end() );
        }

        sub.insert(s[i]);
    }

    return ( sub.size() > max_len ? sub.size() : max_len );
}
```

For the given string `"nfpdmpi"`, I can get the correct output = `5` on my local PC.

But I submit the code onto LeetCode website, and it said my output is `6`.

What's going wrong?

Comment: *But I submit the code onto LeetCode website* -- Then either debug your code, or complain to "LeetCode".

Comment: Also, `max_len = std::max(max_len, sub.size())`  can replace this: `max_len = ( sub.size() > max_len ? sub.size() : max_len )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
sub.erase( sub.find(s[i]), sub.end() );
```

erases a range from an unordered set. Since the order is not defined, this can erase any number of elements including only one. This is probably the reason why results differ. <s>Instead, you want to do</s>

```
sub.clear();
```

because you want to start recognizing a completely new substring.

**Edit:**

That was not a correct solution. Here's one with an ordered set with custom comparator:

```
struct char_occurrence_comp {
  static int lastpos[255];
  bool operator() (const char& lhs, const char& rhs) {
    return lastpos[static_cast<int>(lhs)] < lastpos[static_cast<int>(rhs)];
  }
};
int char_occurrence_comp::lastpos[255] = {}; // initialize with 0

int lengthOfLongestSubstring(const std::string& s) {
  std::set<char, char_occurrence_comp> sub;
  std::size_t max_len = 0;
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i) {
    const auto iter = sub.find(s[i]); 
    if ( iter != sub.end() ) {
      max_len = std::max(max_len, sub.size());
      // end is exclusive, so we need to advance the iterator.
      sub.erase(sub.begin(), std::next(iter, 1));
    }
    // make sure we do not hit the default value (0)
    char_occurrence_comp::lastpos[static_cast<int>(s[i])] = i + 1;
    sub.insert(s[i]);
  }
  return std::max(max_len, sub.size());
}
```

**Edit 2**: Fixed the erase line to erase from start to found char instead of from found char to end.

Comment: So, is it dangerous to use unordered_set::erase() due to undefined order?

Comment: The point is, it has undefined semantics. But I just realized that my fix is not correct since it will not count the characters after the first occurrence of the duplicated character. You have to use a `set` with a `Compare` parameter which orders by input order.

Comment: @flyx *But I just realized that my fix is not correct since it will not count the characters after the first occurrence of the duplicated character.* -- I don't think all of that code you used to address this issue is necessary.  [See this](http://ideone.com/caj4MP)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie counterexample: http://ideone.com/RGqBIm should return 5, returns 3. Aaand that also fails with my code because I did not think it through, will do another edit.